# Windows Java thread affinity with OpenHFT AffinityLock

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, affinity

I'm trying to optimize an application by binding its threads to different cores. To begin with, I would like to bind the entire application to a single core using the Affinity-3.0.6 package from OpenHFT.

So far I've had no luck. At first I imported the package and tried the command

```
AffinityLock al = AffinityLock.acquireCore();
```

was warned about not having JNA access, so I downloaded the jna-4.2.2 package and imported it as well.

After the second import, the same command gives the following error:

> WARN  Affinity - Windows JNA-based affinity not usable because it
>   failed to load! Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef$DWORD

and the execution is not bound to the single core.

I'm blindly trying to give the software what it wants without understanding what it needs.

Comment: Is a simple jna sample in itself working correctly? From the error message I doubt it. Fixing that should then presumably also fix this problem here

Answer (score 0):

i suspect youve added jna.jar, but not jna-platform.jar to your project, and the class that fails to load ispart of platform.

see docs and download links [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).